filter records based on python date range
I have a below csv, where i need to display all records based on the 'CreatedDate' range column. Program should accept 2 input parameters such as FromDate & ToDate.
FromDate should be like '20/09/2020' and ToDate should be like '30/10/2022'
Now the program should display all the records between '20/09/2020 00:00:00' and '30/10/2022 00:00:00'. For this range, ideally it should display the first 3 records, which falls under given range.
No,Name,Sal,CreatedDate
1,ABC,1000,23/09/2020 12:12:00
2,DEF,1000,13/05/2021 10:11:09
3,XYZ,1000,19/10/2022 00:02:10
4,PQR,1000,09/09/2023 01:02:09
5,MNO,1000,30/03/2024 09:10:44

I just started writing a python code on this requirement and share my code shortly.

Where are you stuck? Reading the file? Converting the strings to dates? Finding the records? Do you want the first 3 records in the order they appear in the file or sorted by date? Please create a [mre].

As pointed in the comments, your question needs more precisions so I'll answer it as I understand it: How to select the dates in range based on the file format you gave as an example?
I use the numpy and datetime libraries because I find them more convenient for these operations but pandas is also great for this kind of applications (e.g. this answer).
So here is how you can do it:
from datetime import datetime
import os
import numpy as np

def load_and_select_dates(fpath, start_date, end_date, dfmt):
    content = np.loadtxt(fpath, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', dtype=object)
    dates = np.array([ datetime.strptime(v, dfmt) for v in content[:,-1] ], dtype='datetime64')
    
    idx = np.where(((dates >= start_date) & (dates <= end_date)))[0]
    return content[idx, :]


fpath = os.path.join('.', 'test_data', 'so_filter_record.csv')
dfmt = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'

start_date = np.datetime64(datetime(year=2020, month=9, day=20))
end_date = np.datetime64(datetime(year=2022, month=10, day=30))

content = load_and_select_dates(fpath, start_date, end_date, dfmt)        
print(content)


And here is my result:
[['1' 'ABC' '1000' '23/09/2020 12:12:00']
 ['2' 'DEF' '1000' '13/05/2021 10:11:09']
 ['3' 'XYZ' '1000' '19/10/2022 00:02:10']]

Now, what do we use to estimate which dates are in range?

First I load the csv file using numpy.loadtxt() as it lets me works with numpy methods while also parsing the file content
Secondly, I convert the dates (originally a string) into a datetime.datetime object using datetime.datetime.strptime(), see the documentation for the method behaviour and this Table for the format codes. In my example, the string format is passed using the dfmt variable
Then I convert these dates into np.datetime64 objects and store then into a numpy array (dates in the example). This step is optional as you can also directly work with the datetime.datetime objects but numpy arrays have some interesting properties that I use in the next step
Lastly, I retrieve the indexes of the dates between start_date and end_date using np.where() by applying a array-wide opeartion and only return the values corresponding to these indexes

For the sake of the example, here is how to do it using only the datetime library (numpy is still used to load the file though..). Note that both start_date and end_date are defined as datetime.datetime object in this example.
def load_and_select_dates_native(fpath, start_date, end_date, dfmt):
    content = np.loadtxt(fpath, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', dtype=object)
    idx = [ ii for ii, v in enumerate(content[:,-1]) if datetime.strptime(v, dfmt) >= start_date and datetime.strptime(v, dfmt) <= end_date ]
    
    return content[idx, :]

